# Finding last modified date of files with special extensions

Tags: python

I have written the Python script below to find the last modified date of a file:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for f in files:
        last_modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(f)).day
        #do something
```

This code works fine for normal files like .txt files. However, if it encounters files with extensions like .tar.gz or .run, it throws an error saying "No such file or directory" when finding last_modified.

*** EDIT ***

I realized that, if I change the code as below, it works fine.

```
 for f in files:
        name = os.path.join(root, f)
        last_modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(name)).day
        #do something
```

But why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` return filenames relative to the folder it is walking. E.g. if it is walking a directory called `foo` with a file called `bar`, it will return `bar`, not `foo/bar`. However, since your script (presumably) is not in the folder `os` is `walk`ing, it needs an absolute path, or a path relative to itself. Therefore, you must join the folder path to the filename, so that python can find the file.

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.walk) say:

> Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

Why it happens to work with the text files I'm not sure. Do you have text files with the same name in the folder containing your script?

Comment: No, the text files are in the same folder as the .tar files. And the the python script is in a different folder.

Comment: @drunkenfist Are there text files with the same name in the same directory as the script? And which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm running on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04. The python file is in Desktop/. I have 3 txt files (a.txt, b.txt, c.txt) and a tar file (jdk-8.tar.gz) inside Desktop/sample/1/.

Comment: Is there a file called `a.txt` in `Desktop/`? I'm running Linux and I don't get any fishy behaviour.